# How to convert IQueryable<T> to Expression<Func<T, bool>>?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I just want to build a dynamic filters.
And finally to return

```
 Expression<Func<Event, bool>>
```

I've tried to use the Combine (AndAlso) expressions, but it wasn't workin and finally I found that there are IQueryable queries which works good, but now how can I convert it to the return type -

```
Expression<Func<Event, bool>>?
```

My code:

```
    public IQueryable<Event> GetBySearch(EventFilter search)
    {
        IQueryable<Event> query = this.Context.Events.AsQueryable();
        Expression<Func<Event, bool>> expression = null;

        if (search.CategoryId != 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.CategoryId == search.CategoryId);
        }

        if (search.SubCategoryId != 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.SubCategoryId == search.SubCategoryId);
        }

        expression = query.Expression as Expression<Func<Event, bool>>; //This convert is not working, it returns null.

        return this.Context.Events.Where(expression);
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer (I think you already accepted it an not sure it you still get notifies in that case) that takes Florian's comment into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any reason you don't just do the following:

```
public IQueryable<Event> GetBySearch(EventFilter search)
{
    IQueryable<Event> query = this.Context.Events.AsQueryable();

    if (search.CategoryId != 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.CategoryId == search.CategoryId);
    }

    if (search.SubCategoryId != 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.SubCategoryId == search.SubCategoryId);
    }

    return query;
}
```

As Florian said in the comment, returning IQueryables is to be avoided (when possible). The easy solution is to return a list instead:

```
public List<Event> GetBySearch(EventFilter search)
{
    IQueryable<Event> query = this.Context.Events.AsQueryable();

    if (search.CategoryId != 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.CategoryId == search.CategoryId);
    }

    if (search.SubCategoryId != 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.SubCategoryId == search.SubCategoryId);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This leaks the an not yet evaluated IQueryable which can then result in unexpected results. Because the scope of `search` isn't fixed to `GetBySearch`
-> Bad Practice

Comment: @FlorianDohrendorf True. Easily fixed if you make the function return a `List<Event>` and `return query.ToList()`. Unless you _really_ need that IQueryable that would be the way to go. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

This conversion is not valid because `Where` converts it into a `MethodCallExpression`

This would be valid:

```
MethodCallExpression e = query.Expression as MethodCallExpression;
```